# Setting bg-color of selected Material Chip dynamically causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to set the bg-color of MatChips dynamically when/if they get the selected property. I have a list of options available, which is the same for all users (represented by "chiplists" in app.component of the stackblitz sample) and and a list of the user-selected chips (i.e. "selected"). Both of these lists are dynamic in my app. What I have so far is:

```
<mat-chip #ref="matChip" [selected]="chip.value?.selected
 [ngStyle]="ref.selected && {'background-color': chip.value.color}">
</mat-chip>
```

but it throws `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` for `background-color: undefined` as initial state, which is expected?, I suppose.

Using `[ngClass]` is a possible solution, pairing a custom css class with the `.mat-chip-selected` class, but I can't be generating a bunch of hardcoded css classes, as the colours may change in the future.

The stackblitz link below showcases this behaviour, the error is logged in the console:

<s>https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5kfwc</s>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anjuyf

Notice that while the stackblitz sample is working as intended, albeit with the error, my app doesn't colour the chips at all, whether selected or not.

Edit: My app's angular and material versions are the same as the `package.json` in stackblitz sample.

Edit2: I did add a fork that better showcases what I am after. I am not looking to eliminate the error alone. I'm looking to add colours to the chips dynamically at render time.

Comment: You can just remove this line `[ngStyle]="ref.selected && {'background-color': 'black'}"` and I think it works as you expect it to.

Answer (score 3):

you may remove this line

```
[ngStyle]="ref.selected && {'background-color': 'black'}"
```

to change the color of the selected chip, target it using css.

on app.component.css

```
.my-chip .mat-chip-selected {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked my-chip" *ngFor="let list of lists | keyvalue" multiple>
    <mat-chip #ref="matChip" 
  *ngFor="let chip of list.value | keyvalue"
  (click)="toggle(ref)"
  color="primary"
  [selected]="chip.value.selected">
        {{chip.value.de}}
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

I added a class to mat chip list named my-chip to identity it and target the sub element below which is .mat-chip-selected.

hope it solve your problem

Cheers!

Comment: While it does solve the error, it doesn't provide the dynamic functionality I need. As I said, I can't create static css classes for all the colors, those are sent over from the backend. Each kind of chip will have its own color, and there are about a hundred. SCSS could auto-generate classes, but they're still "static". Thanks for your time!

Comment: if you want to assign color dynamically you may use this [style.background]="color"
and manipulate the color inside your ts

Comment: Indeed if I do `[style.background]="ref.selected ? chip.value.color : '#e0e0e0'"` it does work with no error. I guess the error happens because there's no `backgroundColor` property set at initialisation. If only there's a way to avoid '#e0e0e0', which is the chip's default non selected bg colour, this might be a perfect solution.

Comment: @Aris Kon `[style.background]="ref.selected ? chip.value.color : '#e0e0e0'"` - true this works...but it is always best practice to do the computation in component rather than in HTML..As dont have to lay the burden on HTML..Any how there is selected change event...it can be computed there..

Answer (score 0):

simply call/use this class in mat-chip

```
 .chip{
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    color: #fff;
  }
```